# Typescript function type as a union to function parameter

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

#### Situation

Here is my example setup to reproduce:

```js
type MyType = {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

type MyFuncType = (input: string) => MyType

function myFunction(input: string | MyFuncType) {
    if (typeof input === 'function') {
        // do things
    } else {
        // do other things
    }
}

function test() {

    // works as expected
    myFunction('string')

    // also works, and correctly identifies 'id' as type 'string'
    myFunction((id) => {
        return {
            foo: 'foo',
            bar: 123,
            unrecognisedProperty: 'hello' // does not error
        }
    })
}
```

From this example, you can see I have a function `myFunction()` that accepts either a string, or a function with explicit input and output types.

#### Problem

However when using this function, and providing a `MyFunc` as the input, it does not recognise that I am including an unrecognised property as part of the result.

If I change the code to this, it will work:

```js
function test() {

    myFunction((id): MyType => { // set 'MyType' as the return type
        return {
            foo: 'foo',
            bar: 123,
            unrecognisedProperty: 'hello' // correctly expected error: Object literal may only specify known properties
        }
    })
}
```

While this works.. I don't want to have to define the return type everywhere I use `myFunction()`.

Any ideas if this is achievable, or what I am doing wrong?